# mapping from asynctask to intent service

Tags: android, android-asynctask, intentservice

I have an android app widget where I have used async task for my network calls. NOw I want to shift my calls from asynctask to intent service. doInBackground() 's work can be done in onHandleIntent() but what about onPreExecute() and onPostExecute(). I have the progress bar code in these 2 methods to give a spinning effect for my refresh button.
Where should I put the code for this in intent service?

UPDATE

```
public class StoreWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {

        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_main_layout1);
        mContext = context;
        mProgressBar = new ProgressBar(context);

        Intent localIntent = new Intent(context,StoreWidgetService.class);

        context.startService(localIntent);
//      try {
//          fetchTask.execute().get();
//      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      } catch (ExecutionException e) {
//          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }

        MyCurrentLocation(mContext);
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(mContext);

        updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.next, next_buildButtonPendingIntent(context));

        updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.back, back_buildButtonPendingIntent(context));

        updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.refresh, refresh_buildButtonPendingIntent(context));

//----These commented as they use context and this also gets null when killed----
        //updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.outer_text_view, merchant_buildButtonPendingIntent(context));

        //updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.check_in, checkin_buildButtonPendingIntent(context));

        //updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.image_logo_id, pIcon_buildButtonPendingIntent(context));

        pushWidgetUpdate(context,updateViews);
    }


//my button listeners: next and prev
//--not shown here---


    public static void pushWidgetUpdate(Context context,RemoteViews views){
        System.out.println("Inside pushwidget");
        context = mContext;

        if(context!=null){
            ComponentName myWidget=new ComponentName(context, StoreWidgetProvider.class);
            AppWidgetManager manager=AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            manager.updateAppWidget(myWidget, views);
        }
        }
    }

    public static class StoreWidgetService extends IntentService implements ServerRequestEnvironment{

        public StoreWidgetService() {
            super("StoreWidgetService");
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

//      protected void onPreExecute(){
//          
//          updateViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.refresh, View.GONE);
//          updateViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.progress, View.VISIBLE);
//          pushWidgetUpdate(mContext,updateViews);
//      }
        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
            super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
            return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
        }
        @Override
        public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {


            //my data fetching done with all network calls 

        }

//      protected void onPostExecute(Store storeObj) {
//
//          updateViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.progress, View.GONE);
//          updateViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.refresh, View.VISIBLE);
//          
//
//          pushWidgetUpdate(mContext,updateViews);
//      }


        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to register an `Handler` in your main UI Thread, then you pass this `Handler` to the `IntentService`. Through this handler you can queue `Runnable`s for execution on the UI Thread. Since `AsyncTask` is backed by a `ThreadPool`, I think this is what `AsyncTask` is indeed doing.

You can also try to use the function `runOnUiThread()` (but I think it can be called only by an `Activity` object).

Take a look here for deeper understanding:

http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Comment: I read about it and implemented. The problem now is that once the service gets finished, and if I kill my application, my widget stops working and the application crashes. The logcat gives me null pointer exception for context. How to resolve this? I want that if I kill my application, I should either get the already fetched data or just start the application again. How should I do this ahead?

Comment: Search here for START_STICKY, START_REDILIVER_INTENT and other flags that you can return in the onStartCommand() callback of a started service. These are modes that lets the system handle for you a restart of your service in case it gets killed.

Comment: I tried both of them but they are giving me null pointer exception again wherever context is used. I am using IntentService. I am posting my code up. Please check and guide..

Comment: ALso, after crash, my flags & START_FLAG_REDELIVERY are null.